# How to filter records into different lists effectively in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have an app where I can create todos and list them out according to it's date, 
something like:

```
---------------
Today - [todayDate]
---------------
Todo #1
Todo #2

---------------
Tomorrow - [tomorrowDate]
---------------
Todo #1
Todo #2
```

So how I did this is first I create all the filter-bars

```
<div id="today-filter" class="filter-container">
  <div class="filter-bar">
    <label class="filter-title">Today</label>
    <label class="filter-date">{{generateDate}}</label>
  </div>  
</div>
  {{#each todo in todayFilter itemController='todo'}}
    {{partial 'todolist'}}
  {{/each}}

<div id="tomorrow-filter" class="filter-container">
  <div class="filter-bar">
    <label class="filter-title">Tomorrow</label>
    <label class="filter-date">{{generateDate 1}}</label>
  </div>  
</div>
  {{#each todo in tomorrowFilter itemController='todo'}}
    {{partial 'todolist'}}
  {{/each}}
```

and each of them got their own function in the controller which will return different filtered records:

```
todayFilter: function(){
  return this.get('model').filter(function(todo, index){
    var date = todo.get('date');

    if(moment().isSame(date, 'days')){ //<-- If the date is same as today, then it's today
      return todo;
    }
  });
}.property('model.@each.date'),


tomorrowFilter: function(){
  return this.get('model').filter(function(todo, index){
    var date = todo.get('date');

    if((moment().add(1, 'days')).isSame(date, 'days')){ //<-- If the date is same as today+1 day, then its tomorrow
      return todo;
    }
  });
}.property('model.@each.date'),
```

So the question is if I need to list them out in the range from 'today' -> 'In a week',
I need to write 7 different functions? 
I'm sure there's a better way, and maybe what am I doing now is stupid, but I just couldn't build up a better logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your model so this is based on simple hypothesis :
Lets say your model objects have 2 fields `date` and `available` for instance. A simple thing you could do to create a sorted list, per day is this :

- Create an array of reference day : [1st Jan, 2nd Jan, ..., 31 Dec] (Use moment.js to manage this easily). Each of these should be Date object wrapped in a simple javascript object with a date field : `{ date: new Date() }`
- Use `Array.concat` to merge your model array into this one
- Sort the resulting array based on date property
- Display the resulting array, using the available property to know if this is a real date/event or if it's just a "header" date you created.

Does this help ?

Here is a [complete solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Sephy/0xnpav6L/).
 I did not use concat for simplicity as the solution is already quite complex.

Comment: Thanks Sephy, but I don't quite get the idea, do you mind providing a simple example?

Comment: Yeah, could you provide a simple js fiddle of what you have right now so that I improve it to fit your question ?

Comment: What I'm having is stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439062/ember-js-hiding-a-view-if-no-childview-is-created).

Comment: Editted my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everything Sephy :D
If i'm not using {{view}}, will it be more difficult to make each of them (headers and each non-headers) response to user interactions (touch, swipe etc)?

but this is a different question, i'll mark this as the correct answer :D

Comment: Yeah, write your code, do some testing on your own and then if it doesnt work, post another question with some code, I'll be sure to check ;)